# How to use onClick ONLY if email input field is valid?

Tags: javascript, html, validation

Here's code:

```html
<input id="subscribe-email" type="email" placeholder="john.doe@example.com" />
            <button type="submit" id="subscribe-submit" onClick="javascript:omgemailgone();" />
```

How do I check and run JS function only if email is valid (validation by user-agent, no additional validations)?

UPDATE.
New browsers can validate input=email by themselves, also there are pseudo classes :valid and :invalid. I need to run function only if browser 'knows' that email is valid.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `.checkValidity()` method of the **input element** (in this case, the email input field). This will return a boolean indicating wether the input is valid or not.
Here is a fiddle to play with:

http://jsfiddle.net/QP4Rc/4/

And the code:

```
<input id="subscribe-email" type="email" required="required" placeholder="john.doe@example.com" />

<button type="submit" id="subscribe-submit" onClick="check()">
click me
</button>

function check()
{
  if(!document.getElementById("subscribe-email").checkValidity())
  {

    //do stuff here ie. show errors
    alert("input not valid!");

  }else
  {
      callMeIfValid();
  }
}

function callMeIfValid()
{
  //submit form or whatever
  alert("valid input");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but no, doesn't work. Returns alert but runs other stuff too. In JSFiddle no even alert. [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Moor/j9t38/2/)

Comment: Which browser are you testing in? I've checked my fiddle on Chrome, Firefox and Safari and the alert is showing up just fine. If you want some code to run ONLY if the email field is valid, you should add the code in an else condition. I'll update the code and the fiddle.

Comment: Chrome, IE10, Opera 12. Indeed I solved my question just changed <button onClick> to <input onSubmit>

Comment: Great, glad to hear you got it to work. Please consider accepting the answer so this question won't remain unsolved!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) to check that the email is valid on your `omgemailgone()` :

```
function omgemailgone (){
   var mail = $('#subscribe-email').val();

   //Example of regular expression
   if(mail.match(/YourRegexp/)
   {
      //Do stuff
   }
   else alert("Invalid e-mail");

}
```

*(using jQuery here)*

Comment: Sorry, seems like my question is not asked clearly. new browsers validate input=email by themselves. I need to run function only if browser 'knows' that email is valid.

Comment: Aside of that you (1) forgot the slashes around the regular expression and (2) the regex does not match valid addresses like "marketing@skd.museum".

Comment: I found RFC2822 validation pattern, added slashes, but seems like there's conflict with slashes. Here's a snapshot http://s3.hostingkartinok.com/uploads/images/2013/03/f027bc17748de792ec37d42125af9d61.png

Answer (score 1):

check [Validate email address in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript) for validation and then implement it into an if statement in your omgemailgone method (if valid continue, else do nothing)

edit:

```
function validateEmail(email) { 
    var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\
".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA
-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return re.test(email);
}
```

from the link

Comment: Sorry, seems like my question is not asked clearly. new browsers validate input=email by themselves. I need to run function only if browser 'knows' that email is valid.

Comment: So are you looking for a way to access the value of the validation?

Comment: If it's in a form, the submit button won't do anything until a valid email has been entered.

Comment: Well it's onClick. Valid email or not, `onClick` event works and starts  the function. I tried the solution from @Bigood but it always returns syntax error, even if I changed pattern.

Comment: So just using submit without onClick and passing the form information via POST is not an option? Hmmm, I'm not sure. Have you looked at the answers to the question that me and Mun Mrd linked to? I've adding a different regexp to my original post. Make sure you aren't just missing something silly like a parenthesis. Let me know if you find a way to access the browser's sort of "isValid" method.

Comment: OH MY! Just onSubmit!!! and that solved for me! it runs function only if valid now!

Answer (score 0):

u need a function that validate the email and return true or false
[Validate email address in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript)

```
<button type="submit" id="subscribe-submit" onClick="javascript:validateEmail(document.getElementById('subscribe-email').value) ? omgemailgone() : alert('email is wrong dude');" />
```

This is a quick solution, i recommend you to do it properly, not using inline onclick js

Comment: Sorry, seems like my question is not asked clearly. new browsers validate input=email by themselves. I need to run function only if browser 'knows' that email is valid.

Comment: html5 type=email is not compatible in safari. As a result, everyone can pass this layer of defense by download safari... javascript can be turned off so i recommend using php validation to be as secured as possible